# IAM permission for modifying AWS Lambda execution role

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have a developer working on a Lambda AWS project.  The developer requires to create roles and attach permissions to the lambda function.

I want the developer to be able to independently create the roles for the project as needed but I would prefer not to make the developer a full IAM administrator.
Is there an AWS policy that allows for IAM privileges strictly for AWS service roles that limits the developer to only policies like "AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole" rather than general AWS account policies?
Thanks

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: Check out Permissions Boundaries! It's specifically designed for the use case you described. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_boundaries.html

Comment: Thank you for the link.  I would prefer more broad based rules.  If I have to apply it to that level of granularity, then it is no different then just handling it on a request by request basis.  The problem is I can't anticipate every single permission.

Comment: The [tag:lambda] tag's description says "DO NOT USE FOR THE AWS SERVICE".